# How to disable Nginx test message printing?

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to remove `nginx:` messages

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain" on ip:port, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

while using the `nginx -T` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these messages are sent to stderr, not stdout. You can just filter it out like this:

```
nginx -t 2> /dev/null
```

Since it is sent to stderr you will not be able to remove it with `sed` or similar tools.

If you intend to redirect the output of the command to a file or pipe it into another command you could just ignore it, it won't be directed along with the output from stdout.

Comment: Thank you, it works as I exptected.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. It's kinda the [purpose of the flag](http://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html).

> - -t — test the configuration file: nginx checks the configuration for correct syntax, and then tries to open files referred in the configuration.
> - -T — same as -t, but additionally dump configuration files to standard output (1.9.2).

You can shave them off using `sed` or a similar tool.